# Extract text from multiple .html files and save them in seperate txt files

Tags: python, nlp, data-mining, data-cleaning, data-processing

[files list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVBT4.png)
I have tried to extract text content from 24 folders, every folder has serval (100+) .HTML files,  I need to create 24 .txt files to save text which extracts from .HTML files.

I have done most of the job except saving .txt files, the code I wrote save 24 files all with the same content, I know something wrong in the following part

```
for number in range(1,25):
            with open('Text'+"%02d" % number +" .txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as text:
                for i in passage:
                    text.write(i+' ')
```

All code is listed below

```
# Read files and call functions
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import numpy as np
gap_html = os.listdir('gap-html')
print(gap_html)
# print(folder)
passage = list()
# out = "all.txt"
# def Convertfile():

for textFolders in gap_html:
    # domain = os.path.abspath(r'../gap-html')
    folder = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('gap-html'), textFolders)
    # text_folder=os.path.abspath(folder)
    # Lists the file names under all folders
    textFiles=os.listdir(folder)
    for  textFile in  textFiles :
        file=os.path.join(os.path.abspath(folder), textFile)
        print(file)
        html = open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8").read()
        # print("Start reading file...")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
        page = soup.find_all('span', {"class": "ocr_cinfo"})
        for word in page:
            word = word.get_text()
            passage.append(word)
        for number in range(1,25):
            with open('Text'+"%02d" % number +" .txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as text:
                for i in passage:
                    text.write(i+' ')
```

Comment: have you tried text.writelines(passage) ?

Comment: yes, still get 24 passage with same content